# Comparing dates in Java Spark Dataframe

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have the below Spark dataframe/dataset. Column_2 has dates in string format.

```
Column_1 Column_2
A        2020-08-05
B        2020-08-01
B        2020-09-20
B        2020-12-31
C        2020-05-10
```

My expected output dataframe should have only one row per value in Column_1 and if there are multiple dates in column_2 for same key in column_1, then the next available date should be picked. if only one row is there, then the date should be retained

Expected Output:

```
Column_1 Column_2
A        2020-08-05
B        2020-09-20
C        2020-05-10
```

Is there a way to achieve this Java spark? possibly without using UDF?

Comment: "the next available date should be picked" what is the logic for this? Why do you choose the second not last?

Comment: The next immediate date which is greater than current date. for B in column_1, today is 2020-08-04 and the next date after current date is 2020-09-20.

Comment: The logic is it should be greater than the current date and when there are more than 2 dates which is greater than current date, we have to take the next immediate one available

Comment: Ah, Now I understood.

Comment: Was trying to find if we can do by doing a aggregate and collect list?

Comment: just groypBy min after the filter. But there should be some complex condition for not filter out the single count data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is helpful-

```java
   dataset.show(false);
        dataset.printSchema();
        /**
         *+--------+----------+
         * |Column_1|Column_2  |
         * +--------+----------+
         * |A       |2020-08-05|
         * |D       |2020-08-01|
         * |D       |2020-08-02|
         * |B       |2020-08-01|
         * |B       |2020-09-20|
         * |B       |2020-12-31|
         * |C       |2020-05-10|
         * +--------+----------+
         *
         * root
         *  |-- Column_1: string (nullable = true)
         *  |-- Column_2: string (nullable = true)
         */

        dataset.withColumn("Column_2", to_date(col("Column_2")))
                .withColumn("count", count("Column_2").over(Window.partitionBy("Column_1")))
                .withColumn("positive", when(col("count").gt(1),
                        when(col("Column_2").gt(current_date()), col("Column_2"))
                ).otherwise(col("Column_2")))
                .withColumn("negative", when(col("count").gt(1),
                        when(col("Column_2").lt(current_date()), col("Column_2"))
                ).otherwise(col("Column_2")))
                .groupBy("Column_1")
                .agg(min("positive").as("positive"), max("negative").as("negative"))
                .selectExpr("Column_1", "coalesce(positive, negative) as Column_2")
                .show(false);
        /**
         * +--------+----------+
         * |Column_1|Column_2  |
         * +--------+----------+
         * |A       |2020-08-05|
         * |D       |2020-08-02|
         * |B       |2020-09-20|
         * |C       |2020-05-10|
         * +--------+----------+
         */
```

Comment: Will try this out.. Thanks.. Can you explain the expr("struct(diff, Column_2)")).. I can understand that we are creating a count column and  checking the date difference when the count is greater than 1 here. But didnt understand the rest of part

Comment: also how would this work when all dates given for a key column is less than current date, in that case would it be possible to pick up the closest date that is less than current date?

Comment: @Padfoot13288, Updated an answer, now it will pick the nearest date greater than the current date else nearest date less than current date if no positive. Single date is being as is. I think, the new solution is quite self explainatory

Answer (score 0):

Create the DataFrame First

```
df_b = spark.createDataFrame([("A","2020-08-05"),("B","2020-08-01"),("B","2020-09-20"),("B","2020-12-31"),("C","2020-05-10")],[ "col1","col2"])
_w = W.partitionBy("col1").orderBy("col1")
df_b = df_b.withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(_w))
```

The logic here to pick the second element of each group if any group has a more than one row. In order to do that we can first assign a row number to every group and we will pick first element of every group where row count is 1 and , first 2 row of every group where row count is more than 1 in every group.

```
case = F.expr("""
            CASE WHEN rn =1 THEN 1
                    WHEN rn =2 THEN 1
              END""")

df_b = df_b.withColumn('case_condition', case)
df_b = df_b.filter(F.col("case_condition") == F.lit("1"))
```

**Intermediate Output**

```
+----+----------+---+--------------+
|col1|      col2| rn|case_condition|
+----+----------+---+--------------+
|   B|2020-08-01|  1|             1|
|   B|2020-09-20|  2|             1|
|   C|2020-05-10|  1|             1|
|   A|2020-08-05|  1|             1|
+----+----------+---+--------------+
```

**Now, finally just take the last element of every group --**

```
df = df_b.groupBy("col1").agg(F.last("col2").alias("col2")).orderBy("col1")
df.show()
+----+----------+
|col1|      col2|
+----+----------+
|   A|2020-08-05|
|   B|2020-09-20|
|   C|2020-05-10|
+----+----------+
```

Comment: This works when the second row date is greater than the current date. Assume a scenario where the second row date is less than the current date and on third row i have the date which is greater than current date

Answer (score 0):

**SCALA:** This will give the result.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy("Column_1")

df.withColumn("count", count("Column_2").over(w))
  .withColumn("later", expr("IF(Column_2 > date(current_timestamp), True, False)"))
  .filter("count = 1 or (count != 1 and later = True)")
  .groupBy("Column_1")
  .agg(min("Column_2").alias("Column_2"))
  .orderBy("Column_1")
  .show(false)

+--------+----------+
|Column_1|Column_2  |
+--------+----------+
|A       |2020-08-05|
|B       |2020-09-20|
|C       |2020-05-10|
+--------+----------+
```

It has an exception that if the count of the dates for the `Column_1` is larger than `1` and there is no date after the `current_timestamp`, it will not give the result for the value of `Column_1`.